# SQL Server Import Export Wizard - Error There is already an object named

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-import-wizard

I'm utilizing the SQL Server Import Export Wizard and I have saved that picks up a txt file and imports to SQL Server. I have to delete the old table or I get an error each time I run. There is already an object name...

My question. Is there a way to truncate the old table and add the new table within this process?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to drop and recreate the table through the SQL Server Import Export Wizard by going to the Edit mapping and selecting "Drop and re-create destination table"